# jQuery: Get IDs from elements and assign them as attribute values to other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get each ID from a series of slides (section and aside elements), then assign those IDs to the corresponding navigation element's data-target attribute as it's value. I'm using the gridscroll.js plugin, so the nav elements are created dynamically.

The plugin I'm using is here (in case that helps):
https://github.com/mknecht/gridscrolling.js

My HTML:
(I'd like to grab the IDs from each of these elements...)

```
    <section id="section-1a"></section>

    <section id="section-2a"></section>
    <aside id="section-2b"></aside>
    <aside id="section-2c"></aside>
    <aside id="section-2d"></aside>

    <section id="section-3a"></section>
    <aside id="section-3b"></aside>
    <aside id="section-3c"></aside>

    <section id="section-4a"></section>
    <aside id="section-4b"></aside>

    <section id="section-5a"></section>
```

The JQ I used to add an attribute to each dynamically created nav element. I just inserted numbers as a placeholder:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".gridscrolling-overview-square").each(function(index) {
           $(this).attr("data-target", index);
    });
```

I am grabbing the IDs and putting them into an array:

```
        var slideids = $(".slides").map(function(){
            return this.id;
        }).get();
```

The navigation markup that the plugin renders on page load with my unique data-target values added:

(I'd like to assign the IDs values that I grabbed to each of it's  corresponding nav elements' data-target attributes. The nav items and their corresponding slides are each in sequential order. )

```
    <div id="gridscrolling-overview">
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-main" data-target="0"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-main gridscrolling-looking-at" data-target="1"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="2"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="3"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="4"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-main" data-target="5"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="6"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="7"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-main" data-target="8"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-aside" data-target="9"></div>
        <div class="gridscrolling-overview-square gridscrolling-ov-main" data-target="10"></div>
    </div>
```

Also, if there is a better approach than the one I have started, I'm open to suggestions :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if everything is in the same order:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gridscrolling-overview-square").each(function(index) {
       $(this).attr("data-target", slideids[index]);
});
```

If not, when you can create the elements you can assign them ids with a counter so you can map things properly:

```
$(this).attr("id", "slide"+index);
```

Comment: Ha! Yes! Worked like a charm. Thank you, JSP64 :)

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple!